# Users with no posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

User

```
has_many :posts
```

In Model Post I already have a scope that returns all posts that where created in a given month. So I can do: `Post.in_month("2012-01-01")`

How do I get all Users that have made no posts in a given month using ActiveRecord::Relation or Arel?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
User.joins(:posts).where("count(posts.id) = 0 AND posts.created_at BETWEEN (?) AND (?)", "2012-01-01", "2012-02-01")
```

Comment: Hmm. I'd like to use the scope in_month that I have already defined. Is there a way without using pure SQL? Does joins(:posts).in_month("2012-01-01").count.eq(0) work?